# A word that is similar to 'duress' that captures this 'invisible pressure' that one feels

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

I am looking for a word that captures that feeling of being pressured (to do something) by an *invisible force*.

For example, when I go shopping at the local farmers market, the vendors have this approach where they open up a bag to pack the crops that you would presumably purchase. The invisible force in this situation adds pressure to me to actually make a purchase since I have witnessed the vendor opened up a new bag already.

This word *duress* is closely related to the situation that I have described above, but I think duress is too extreme of a manner to describe it; the word implies a pressure that is forcibly perhaps through a threat whereas I hope to capture a more lighter sentiment of 'making a decision under distress'.

Does a suitable word exist in the English language for this circumstance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in:

When I go shopping at the local farmers market, I feel **compelled** to make a purchase when the hard-working farmers open up a new bag to proudly show me their wares.

**compel**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/compel)

> 3. To exert a strong, irresistible **force** on; sway:

Answer (score 1):

You were **[pressed](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/press)**. It expresses persuasion with lots of effort or pressure.

> 4a : to exert influence on : CONSTRAIN
>
> b : to try hard to persuade : BESEECH, ENTREAT
>
> 5 : to move by means of pressure
>
> 6a : to lay stress or emphasis on
>
> b : to insist on or request urgently

Hence:

> The vendors pressed me to make a purchase.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I opted for 'compelled' because it does evoke that 'invisible hand' force on the mind while the word 'pressed' would partially imply a bit of physical force (even if not used in that context).